# concatenating a string in R with commas

Tags: r, paste, string-concatenation

I have some information in one .txt file like this:

```
cars.txt

    Ford               1000
    Mercedes           2000
    Lada               3000
    Chevrolet          5000
```

and I want to read some elements of this .txt file and to convert them into one line separated by commas. I will save that in another file, so I need something like (with the NAME string added):

```
NAME,Mercedes,Lada
```

I have tried the following code:

```
conn=file("cars.txt",open="r")
control<-readLines(conn)
data<-strsplit(control,"\t")
c<-1
cars<-c()
for (j in 1:4)
{
    cars[[c]]<-data[[j]][1]
    cd<-cd+1
}
carsd<-paste(cars,sep=",")
print(carsd)
```

But no results at all, any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
data <- read.table("cars.txt", sep = "\t")
paste(c("NAME", data[,1]), collapse = ",")
```

If `read.table` is not compatible with your data (e.g. non tabular data), here is how I would adapt your code:

```
control <- readLines("cars.txt")
data    <- strsplit(control, "\t")
brands  <- sapply(data, `[`, 1)
paste(c("NAME", brands), collapse = ",")
```

Comment: I think it does work even with tabs. If it didn't, you could use sep='\t'.

Comment: when I use data<-read.table("cars.txt") I got the following error Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings